# How do I change the background color of day?

Tags: reactjs, react-day-picker

I'm using react-day-picker, and I'm having trouble finding the ways to change the background color of the days when it's **not hovered or focused**. I was only able to change the background color by changing `--rdp-background-color`.

However, it only changes the background color for the hovered/focused elements.

```
.rdp {   
--rdp-cell-size: 40px; /* Size of the day cells. */   
--rdp-caption-font-size: 18px; /* Font size for the caption labels. */   
--rdp-accent-color: #0000ff; /* Accent color for the background of selected days. */   
--rdp-background-color: #e7edff; /* Background color for the hovered/focused elements. */   
--rdp-accent-color-dark: #3003e1; /* Accent color for the background of selected days (to use in dark-mode). */   
--rdp-background-color-dark: #180270; /* Background color for the hovered/focused elements (to use in dark-mode). */   
--rdp-outline: 2px solid var(--rdp-accent-color); /* Outline border for focused elements */   
--rdp-outline-selected: 3px solid var(--rdp-accent-color); /* Outline border for focused _and_ selected elements */   
--rdp-selected-color: #fff; /* Color of selected day text */ 
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/gpbl/react-day-picker/blob/main/src/style.css) is the link to react-day-picker's style sheet. I also tried setting `.rdp-day`, it doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe you should add a tag in your question for react-day-picker